# Tomcat: default value for Cache-Control

Tags: tomcat, cache-control

I'm working on one web app and found that the Cache-Control is  private for all resource. I tried to find a place where this is set, but i didn't find any xml or property file with setting for the http header. Also i didn't find any docs is related to this issue.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authentication valves do this automatically to prevent protected resources from being cached in a pubic cache since that would be a security vulnerability. Details of configuration options for twekaing this are in the docs:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html#Authentication